# This method that determines the winner of a Mancala does not work

Tags: java, boolean

Mancala is a fascinating game that I programmed in Java. On the image below we see a Mancala gameboard. For my problem you need to know that a A1-A6,B1-B6 are called pits and the big pits are called kalahs.

[image: The mancala game]
<sub>(source: [pressmantoy.com](http://www.pressmantoy.com/instructions/mancala_img1.jpg))</sub>

The pits A1-A6 and right kalah belongs to player A and pits B1-B6 and left kalah to player B.

The game ends when all six pits on one side of the gameboard are empty or when there are more than 24 pits in one player's kalah. This is what I tried to program in a boolean method (which returns true if there is a winner so I can use other method to tell who it is):

```
public boolean isThereAWinner() {
    ArrayList <SuperPit> pitsOfOwner = owner.getmyPits();       
    ArrayList <SuperPit> pitsOfOpponent = owner.getopponent().getmyPits();
    for (int i = 0; i < pitsOfOwner.size(); i++) {
        if (pitsOfOwner.get(i).isValidPlayOption() == true) 
            return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pitsOfOpponent.size(); i++) {
        if (pitsOfOpponent.get(i).isValidPlayOption() == true) 
            return false;
    }
    if (owner.getKalah().getSeed() > 24) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Where:

```
protected int seed;

public int getSeed() { 
    return seed;    
}

public boolean isValidPlayOption() {
    if (getSeed() > 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

The oppositepit() and nextPit() methods work. The myPits ArrayLists contain the pits that belong to the two respective players.

I thought that this method should work since if one player no longer has seeds in his pit the game should stop. The method isThereAWinner() is run every time a player makes a move.

Unfortunately, the method always returns false. I have no idea why and hope someone here can provide me with some insight.

Comment: Create unit tests.    One of your assumptions about the state of the board is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always returning false because of :

```
for (int i = 0; i < pitsOfOwner.size(); i++) {
if (pitsOfOwner.get(i).isValidPlayOption() == true) 
        return false;
}
```

The moment any pit has seeds, it returns false, even if the other board is completely empty.

How about:

```
int sum1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pitsOfOwner.size(); i++) {
    sum1 += pitsOfOwner.get(i).getSeed();
}
if (sum1 == 0) return true; // all pits are empty
```

Answer (score 1):

- If one player has one valid play option, you already return a value. You need to continue checking.
- You don't return true if a player doesn't have a move.
- What about checking the opponent's kalah?
- `== true` is redundant.

**Code:**

```
public boolean isThereAWinner() {
    ArrayList <SuperPit> pitsOfOwner = owner.getmyPits();       
    ArrayList <SuperPit> pitsOfOpponent = owner.getopponent().getmyPits();
    boolean hasLost = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < pitsOfOwner.size() && hasLost; i++) {
        if (pitsOfOwner.get(i).isValidPlayOption()) 
            hasLost = false;
    }
    if (hasLost) return true;

    hasLost = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < pitsOfOpponent.size() && hasLost; i++) {
        if (pitsOfOpponent.get(i).isValidPlayOption()) 
            hasLost = false;
    }
    if (hasLost) return true;

    if (owner.getKalah().getSeed() > 24) return true;

    if (owner.getopponent().getKalah().getSeed() > 24) return true;

    return false;
}
```

The `&& hasLost` is just an optimization to stop the loop once you find a move.

**With less redundancy:**

```
private boolean hasLost(Player player)
{
    boolean hasLost = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < player.getmyPits().size() && hasLost; i++) {
        if (player.getmyPits().get(i).isValidPlayOption()) 
            hasLost = false;
    }
    return (hasLost || player.getopponent().getKalah().getSeed() > 24);
}

public boolean isThereAWinner() {
    if (hasLost(owner)) return true;
    if (hasLost(owner.getopponent())) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort and nice explanation how to remove redundancy. Somehow this solution still does not work though. I combined the two solutions of you into one and it works now. Unfortunately my winner procedure does not display the correct amount of seeds yet (when the game is ended you collect all the seeds from opponent and add them to your own kalah), but I am working on that. :-) best wishes